# How to create a script with variables inside another script?

Tags: bash

So i am trying to create a script inside another script, but the issue i have encountered is that the variables in the script i am trying to create are getting filled by the script that is creating it. That is a little confusing, but i think it makes sense. Ill give an example...

```
#/bin/bash
cat <<EOF | tee -a ./newscript.sh
variable1=$(ls /home/ | wc -l)
variable2=$(expr $variable1 + 1)
EOF
```

The results of this script create a script that has those values filled out already, like this

```
variable1=*some number*
variable2=*another number*
```

The intended result would be to add that entire section of code into the script unchanged. How would I do this? My current workaround is just using wget to get the script from github, but i would much rather have it be all contained in one script without having to call out to another service to work. Thanks

Comment: The literal answer to your questions is to quote your heredoc (`<<'EOF'` instead of `<<EOF`), but if you want to perform the operations from one script inside another script, it makes more sense to _source_ the other script than to literally copy its text around.

Comment: oh wow okay thank you. that fixed the issue lol. for my application, this works much better than sourcing the script from elsewhere. but thanks for the answer!